# How to create a button in HTML for a NodeJS function?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to create a button, that rotates the screen in my `Electron app`. [The NPM package functions are straight-forward](https://www.npmjs.com/package/display-rotation-windows). I created a script containing

```
const displayRotationWindows = require('display-rotation-windows');
const buttonCW = document.getElementById('rotateCW');
buttonCW.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    displayRotationWindows.rotateCW();
});
```

and added it in my **index.html** via

```
<script src="displayRotation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The script is supposed to listen to the button or anchor tag with the id `rotateCW` being clicked and then call the display rotation function. The rotation function works for sure, because when I start the application and then run the displayRotation.js containing just the function displayRotationWindows.rotateCW(); from VSCode, the screen does rotate.

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#aside-communication-between-processes

Comment: Any error messages? (Check both the Chromium JavaScript console and your terminal for the output of the main process)

Comment: It says "document is not defined".

Comment: All 3 lines following require should be in a function called later - not before body onload event. Even from that error it seems this code run before page your is ready.

Comment: What do you mean by later? As far as I understand, the code links buttonCW to the element with the id="rotateCW". It listens to buttonCW and then calls the function. At least that is what I want it to do.

Comment: I never really understood this main and renderer process. I have watched some tutorials on it and also read a little, but don't understand why I must use it. I just want to call a function in some script from my index.html